# Sql code to format date

Tags: sql

I´m using this code below to get this date output ->  01-Jul-2016 09:15:20

```
${SQL:SELECT STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(char(20), getdate(), 113),3,1, '-'),7,1,'-')}"
```

Can you tell me which code need I use to get this output ?

01-Jul 09:15

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not elegant, but if you don't have 2012 as Gordon mentioned

```
SELECT Replace(Replace(Substring(CONVERT(char(20), getdate(), 113),1,17),' ','-'),'-'+DateName(YY,GetDate())+'-',' ')
```

Returns
01-Jul 11:00

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It´s working fine in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012+ supports `format()`:

```
select format(getdate(), 'dd-MMM hh:mm', 'en-US')
```